# Why I can't open my localhost site with internet IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

About two years ago, I had a different connection and users—even me—were able to open my site via my internet IP or connect to my TeamSpeakServer. But ever since I changed—I reinstalled Windows too—no one is able to connect connect to my IP or ping my IP. Recently I installed “No-IP” DNS (as I have dynamic IP) I associated a domain with it thought it’d solve it but it did not. Why is this happening?

I’m connected via LAN to a router and that router is connected to our main internet DSL Line, there are other computers connected to that LAN too so we all have same IP.

Comment: Have you asked your ISP?  Most nowadays block ports so you can't run a webserver without purchasing business-class service.

Comment: Have you set up portforwarding on your router?

Comment: @Debra they haven't blocked any ports.

Comment: @Paul I did try setting 80 port but it didn't help, are there list of ports that needs to be added so that internet users can ping me?

Comment: Ping is not normally forwardable on a domestic router. Where did you try setting port 80? Can you screenshot it?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible causes.  With the network setup that you specified, Paul's comment is right: port forwarding is required.  This is the most likely problem.  Check that your router config will forward ports to your internal address.  How you do that will depend on what router you use.  You'll need to know the internal IP address of your machine.  (Use IPConfig.)  You'll also need to know what ports to forward: I mention these later.

You may wish to verify that TeamSpeakServer is listening on your internal IP address.  To verify that, figure out what your internal IP address is (via IPConfig if you're using Microsoft Windows) and then see if TeamSpeakServer is listening on that port (by using "netstat -na", or, more clearly in Microsoft Windows, "netstat -nab").  TeamSpeakServer's executable file should be listening on 0.0.0.0 or an IPv4 address that you're actually using.  (That's making the probably-correct assumption that you're using IPv4.)

A firewall could be blocking this.  This could include Windows Firewall, which you might have enabled by default.  [Opening Ports for TeamSpeak 3 Server on the Microsoft WindowsXPFirewallFirewall Firewall](http://portforward.com/english/routers/firewalling/Microsoft/WindowsXPFirewallFirewall/TeamSpeak_3_Server.htm).  (Even if you're not using Windows XP, these instructions will likely be close enough that they may help you with newer operating systems.)  Namely, it points out that TCP port 10011 and TCP port 30033 and UDP port 9987 may be useful.

Debra's comment is another great suggestion.  Since it looks like TeamSpeak uses ports other than 80 and 443, webserver blocking would not affect TeamSpeak.  But ISP port blocking could.  That may be less likely (in my very-possibly-incorrect opinion), but some ISPs may indeed do such a thing, and it would be an absolute showstopper if it was the case.  If none of these work, provide details like your internal IPv4 address and what "netstat -nab" reports.